# How to insert data in auth_table from servlet?

Tags: java, django, oracle, servlets, django-rest-framework

How do i insert data into auth_user table of django rest framework from servlets. I have connected the servlet to the database. I tried inserting the username and password by

```
query = new String("insert into Auth_User(password, username) values('"+pswd+"','"+loginid+"')");
st.executeUpdate(query);
```

But i am getting an error- java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00947: not enough values. I figured there are other fields in the auth_user table which needs to be filled. So how do i insert the date_joined value and others in the table using java commands.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your insert statement but "password" can be reserved word, can you try to rename it and check if it's working?...

Comment: These are the fields in the auth_user django model - id, password, username, is_staff, is_active, is_superuser, and date_joined. And i am using this query to insert the data in database - query = new String("insert into Auth_User" + "(password, is_superuser, username is_staff, is_active, date_joined) values" + "('pswd',0,'loginid',0,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
There are other nullable fields as well, so i am not inserting them. The id is auto incremented using a trigger so i am not inserting that as well.

Comment: there's no comma "," between username and is_staff in your insert statement

Comment: yeah. i figured that out, thanx though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comma was missing, query works fine now.